# Ring Sandwiched between PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

If I have three commutative rings $R \subset S \subset T$, such that $R$ and $T$ are principal ideal domains, will this imply that $S$ itself is a principal ideal domain?

Comment: If we wish, we may even assume that Frac($R$) = Frac($T$).

Comment: Of course not, even if $R$ and $T$ are fields: take for $S$ any integral domain containing $R$, and for $T$ its fraction field.

Comment: What if I change R and T to be Bezout domains; does this imply that S will be a Bezout domain?

Comment: A field is a Bezout domain.

Comment: Again, assuming that R and T have the same fraction field.

Comment: If $R$ and $T$ have the same fraction field the answer is yes, as any ring in between $R$ and its fraction field can be obtained from $R$ by inverting some set of primes.

Comment: Take $\Bbb{Z} \subseteq R \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ where $R$ is the ring of all algebraic integers in $\Bbb{C}$. The ring $R$ cannot possibly be a PID because it is non-Noetherian.

Answer (score 3):

For the original question, one counterexample would be $\Bbb Z \subseteq \Bbb Z[x]\subseteq \Bbb Q (x)$.

The ring in the middle is Noetherian but isn't Bezout, and thus certainly isn't a principal ideal ring.

---

If, as you mentioned in the comment, we add that $Frac(R)=Frac(T)$, then the picture is different. By gathering up all the denominators of fractions of $R$ lying in $S$, you have a multiplicative set $M$ such that $M^{-1}R=S$. It's elementary to show that a localization of a principal ring is principal, and the localization of a Bezout ring is Bezout, so $S$ will have either of these properties if $R$ does. In this situation, $T$ doesn't play any role.

Answer (score 2):

$k[t^3]\subset k[t^2,t^3]\subset k[t]$ .